# How get laravel route alias?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have next code

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin.search.'], function () {
    Route::get('admin/query', ['uses' => 'Admin\AdminSearchController@query', 'as' => 'query']);
    Route::get('admin/search', ['uses' => 'Admin\AdminSearchController@index', 'as' => 'index');
    Route::post('admin/search', ['uses' =>'Admin\AdminSearchController@search', 'as' => 'full');
});
```

And i check route in layout

```
@if (!Route::is('admin.search.index') || !Route::is('admin.search.full'))
      @include('partials.forms.global_search')
@endif
```

But is not work. How i can know route which now i am ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this function, it returns you route name in your case it will be `admin.search.query` etc...

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName()
```

And check it's `!Route::is('admin.search.full')` doesn't make sense because it's a post route handler.

In your case code will be

```
@if (Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName() === 'admin.search.search')
      @include('partials.forms.global_search')
@endif
```